# How can I more "pages" in one pages?

Tags: html

How can I have more different pages on one HTML page? But see only one page at time? for example I have two different paragraphs: News and Contact - how can i see at the beggining only news and then click on button to see contact and hide news?

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically all you have to do is wrap all your paragraphs into different div tags and then on click of one button we'll hide one section (in this case News section) and show the other (in our case Contact) and then again and again over. In this case, we'll need jQuery, we could also do this without jQuery but with it, it's easier.You can check this JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ejdrien/hme5bsw7/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="news">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <p>This is content of News section!</p>
    <button id="newsButton">Click me to show Contact section!</button>
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <p>This is content of contact section!</p>
    <button id="contactButton">Click me to show News section!</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //This hides contact section while documents loads
    $("#contact").hide();
    $("#contactButton").hide();
    //When you newsButton it'll hide news and show contact
    $("#newsButton").on("click", function() {
        //Hides news section
        $("#news").hide();
        $("#newsButton").hide();
        //Shows contact section
        $("#contact").show();
        $("#contactButton").show();
    });
    //When you contactButton it'll hide contact and show news
    $("#contactButton").on("click", function() {
        //Shows News section
        $("#news").show();
        $("#newsButton").show();
        //Hides contact section
        $("#contact").hide();
        $("#contactButton").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [Bootstrap accordion](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php)

Comment: thanks for your reply but I was looking for Ejdrien's method

Answer (score 0):

You can create two paragraphs and hide one (first paragraph). Using JavaScript, create a event to change in the button event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I  used that from Ejdrien's post, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to toggle `display: none` and `display: block` in a `div`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
    
    $("#contact").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="news" class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact" class="tab-content">
            <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```